# Find a string pattern in a file from an NSIS script

Tags: string, find, nsis

In an NSIS installer script, I'm trying to check if a given httpd.conf file contains the following line :

> Include "c:\xxx\yyy.conf"

If so, then my installer script would not append it to the file, otherwise, it would append it.

I've come through {LineFind} but not sure this really makes what i'm trying to achieve.

What could be the simplest way to do a kind of "grep" on a text file from an NSIS script ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample for searching for a given line into a file, using the LogicLib for ease of syntax. The search is stopped as soon as the line is found. This sample works on the sample script itself:

```
# find.nsi : sample for LineFind from TextFunc.nsh
!include "textfunc.nsh"
!include "logiclib.nsh"
OutFile "find.exe"

!define lookfor `Section`   ;will find
;!define lookfor `Sectionn` ;will not find
Var found

Section
    StrCpy $found 0
    ${LineFind} "find.nsi" "/NUL" "1:-1" "GrepFunc"

    ${if} $found = 1 
        MessageBox MB_OK "string found"
    ${else}
        MessageBox MB_OK "string NOT found"
    ${endIf}

SectionEnd

Function GrepFunc
    ${TrimNewLines} '$R9' $R9
    DetailPrint "test for line $R8 `$R9`"
    ${if} $R9 == "${lookfor}" 
        StrCpy $found 1         ;set flag
        Push "StopLineFind"     ;stop find
    ${else}
        Push 0                  ;ignore -> continue
    ${endIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Merci !